# Average/Aggregation of 10 Discrete Probabilty Distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, aggregation

I have 2 experiments, where I have repeated each 10 times (20 experiments in total).

I want to compare experiment A with experiment B. I create a probability distribution from each exp (20 prob distributions) and I would like to now compare exp A with exp B.

I want to do some sort of aggregation (almost like average) on all probabilty distributions for A and plot and compare that with all probabilty distributions for B. Is there a way of doing this?

Note some of these distributions are not necessarily normal.

Comment: There are many possibilities, not quite sure what you want. For starters, you can do 20 boxplots side by side, first exp A, then exp B, and then you can see whether they are systematically different. This could also help to assess non-normality.